# i change the URL type and make it SEO friendly and get 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

before I change the URL it was like 
https://dastbaz.ir/quotes.php?id=1 
and then I used this PHP code

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
    $row = fetch_array($result);
    $author_name = $_GET['id']."/".$row['author_name'];
    $journalName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $author_name);

    if (!empty($row)) {
        Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: " . $journalName . " ");
    } else {
        $html = "Error: cannot find short URL";
    }
}
```

and select author_name by using id in URL and used it in URL and now it's like:
https://dastbaz.ir/1/author_name
but I have a problem with.HTACCESS and I get 404 on these pages. if there need any changes in.HTACCESS please help me to deal with that. 
htaccess Code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php56 .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$/^(\w+) /quotes.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dastbaz.ir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dastbaz.ir/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please post your htaccess code.

Comment: update the htaccess or create one for your self if you cant access it

Comment: here is the htaccess code:
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)$/^(\w+) /quotes.php?id=$1

Comment: are you using any tool to test? like `curl` or `wget` ?

Comment: The way you are trying to use `$` and `^`  inside your pattern makes no sense. These only have special meaning, if they are at the very start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the pattern, but you are using them inside, so they mean a _literal_  `^`  and `$` – which your URL does not contain.

Comment: after I change the URL type to https://web.ir/1/author_name I getting 404  from the server , @benc I don't use any test tools